# Question title cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[This question's](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/46491/23061) original title was:

> Proper way to "Link" 2 image frames together to create a thumbnail version of that image frame (that auto-updates)

Which made it too wide for the width of a question (I have since changed the title to a more appropriate title).

The problem is, with the original long title, the end of the question title was cutoff. On other StackExchange sites like StackOverflow these titles automatically flow to a new line - and thus all of the title can be seen.

Are the titles on GD.SE supposed to be the way they are or are they supposed to overflow like on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is now fixed, it will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! There's [another design issue](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2377/23061) I posted about in case you haven't seen it

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug. `#question-header` 40px is wider than `#content` due to the 20px padding.

[image: Screenshot: div#question-header]

[image: Screenshot: div#content]

Changing the width of `#question-header` to `940px` should do the trick:

[image: Screenshot: recommended fix]